# Get info of an item from database in pre-put callback in Eve

Tags: python, mongodb, put, eve

I have items with `subId` and some other fields stored in mongoDB. Before the `PUT` request is submitted, I want to check if the `subId` which is sent in the header of the `PUT` request is equal to the `subId` of the desired item which is stored in mongoDB. So, I decided to use `pre_put_callback` to do this check. Now I can get the `subId` from header of the request in this function, but I don't know how to access the `subId` of the item from mongoDB whose `_id` is provided by the user as the path of the request in `pre_put_callback` function. Is there a way to access the `subId` of that item (which is stored in MongoDB) from `pre_put_callback` function?

Comment: Have you checked event hooks in the docs? http://python-eve.org/features.html#event-hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an item of MongoDB database from a pre-request event hook such as `pre_put_callback` using `current_app` of `flask` package. For example for pre_PUT event hook it can be accessed as below:

```py
from flask import current_app as app
from eve import Eve

def pre_put_callback(resource, request, lookup):
    resource_db = app.data.driver.db[resource]
    item = resource_db.find_one(lookup)
    print("DB Item: ", item)

app = Eve()
app.on_pre_PUT += pre_put_callback

app.run()
```